# Run octave script from powershell and wait for it to finish

Tags: powershell, batch-file, octave

I'm trying to run a very simple octave .m file from Powershell but i can't manage to make powershell wait for it to finish. In fact, it launches the script execution but then immediatly starts executing the next line.

As I said the script is really simple, just a test

```
a=100
% Saving just to be sure that the script excuted
save test.mat a

% Pausing to be sure that the execution is not too fast  
pause(10)
disp("no way")
```

And in powershell I simply run

```
octave --persist test.m
```

but prompt doesn't wait for octave to finish execution. It seems somehow it runs it async in another process.

I've tried running the script from batch with the wait option

```
START /W octave --persist test.m
```

but the result still the same.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to @Trey Nuckolls I'm using this patch:

```
$Donefilename = 'done'
if (Test-Path $Donefilename) {
    Remove-Item $Donefilename
    Write-Host "Last execution $Donefilename has been deleted"
  }
else {
    Write-Host "$Donefilename doesn't exist"
}

octave --persist test.m

do{
    $i++
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 
    $OctaveComplete = Test-Path -Path $Donefilename 
 }
 until ($OctaveComplete -or ($i -eq 30))
```

Making the octave script writing an empty "done" file at the end of execution. Not the best solution although; I'm not able to redirect the execution output for example.

**EDIT 2**

So, i managed to find the problem thanks to **all your responses and comments**. It seems that when i was calling `octave` from windows it wasn't calling the executable but something else. Getting the right path and executing:

```
& "C:/Program Files/GNU Octave/Octave-6.4.0/mingw64/bin/octave-cli.exe" test.m
```

works perfectly (you need just to add `exit` at the end of the script). So, it was a matter of path.

Comment: If you want it to run synchronously where it waits to be completed, you can try using the invocation/call operator: `& octave --persist test.m`. I am not familiar with what Octave is but, can only assume it's some software which is getting executed to run those arguments given to it in it's own *engine*?

Comment: You need to start Octave in the CLI mode, not the GUI mode.  Add `--no-gui` to your command.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i've tried but without any success.

Comment: @CrisLuengo this seems nice but it just start another terminal interface, in the original terminal the command run and immediatly skip to the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider putting a wait loop into your invoking script like...

```
do{
   $i++
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 #Assuming that 30 seconds is way too long
   $OctiveComplete = <**Boolean returning function that becomes 'True' when run is complete**>
}
until ($OctiveComplete -or ($i -eq 4))
```

This would go directly after the line that invokes Octave.

Comment: Is not quite clear how I should know when run is complete